# Verilog : Is there an idiom for an incrementing compile-time counter

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog

Is there an idiom in Verilog or Systemverilog that will allow me to incremenent a compile-time variable? I want be able to do something like this:

```
wire [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec;

localparam IRQ_COUNT = 0;
`ifdef INCLUDE_UART
uart inst_uart(
    .irq( irq_vec[IRQ_COUNT] ),
    ...other ports...
);
IRQ_COUNT = IRQ_COUNT + 1;
`endif

`ifdef INCLUDE_TIMER
timer inst_timer(
    .irq( irq_vec[IRQ_COUNT] ),
    ...other ports...
);
IRQ_COUNT = IRQ_COUNT + 1;
`endif
```

The thing I am trying to accomplish is to have a synthesis parameter file that lets me chose the number and type of resources that I include in the system, and make the address map and IRQ assignments and such automatically adjust themselves depending on the selected synthesis options. Or does anyone have a better method to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Looks like `generate if` would work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not change it on the fly.

But there can be solutions, see bellow code and try to understand,

```
wire [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec;
integer IRQ_COUNT;

wire is_uart; 
wire is_timer;

`ifdef INCLUDE_UART
assign is_uart = 1'b1;
`else
assign is_uart = 1'b0;
`endif

`ifdef INCLUDE_TIMER
assign is_timer = 1'b1;
`else
assign is_timer = 1'b0;
`endif

always @ (*)
begin
  if(is_uart)
  begin 
    inst_uart(irq_vec[IRQ_COUNT] ), ...other ports...); // make module into task or function, whichever is applicable
    IRQ_COUNT = IRQ_COUNT + 1;
  end

  if(is_timer)
  begin
    inst_timer(irq_vec[IRQ_COUNT],...other ports...); // make module into task or function, whichever is applicable
    IRQ_COUNT = IRQ_COUNT + 1;
  end
end

task inst_uart (
  input [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec,
  // input output other ports;

  ...
 );
  wire [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec_v;
  // define local variables

  begin
    irq_vec_v = irq_vec;  // IO to varible
    // .. other port assignment .. 

    // do operations

    // assign operations and produced result will be stored into outputs
   end
   // Variable to IO assignment 
 endtask

task inst_timer (
  input [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec,
  // input output other ports;

  ...
 );
  wire [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec_v;
  // define local variables

  begin
    irq_vec_v = irq_vec;  // IO to Variable
    // .. other port assignment .. 

    // do operations

    // assign operations and produced result will be stored into outputs
   end
   // Variable to IO
 endtask
```

Yes, you can say it is limitation but if you want to do it you have to compromise with the hardware utilization, even if you use only timer if must generate hardware for both, which will going to un-useful.

What I would suggest is, please change your architecture or do something in RTL of UART or TIMER, truly speaking, combine both in single module and handle as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below. Have seperate IRQ parameters for each component and set them based on what was included previously:

```
wire [MAX_IRQ:0] irq_vec;

localparam UART_IRQ = 0;
`ifdef INCLUDE_UART
uart inst_uart(
    .irq( irq_vec[UART_IRQ] ),
    ...other ports...
);
localparam TIMER_IRQ = UART_IRQ + 1;
`else
localparam TIMER_IRQ = UART_IRQ;
`endif

`ifdef INCLUDE_TIMER
timer inst_timer(
    .irq( irq_vec[TIMER_IRQ] ),
    ...other ports...
);
localparam SOME_OTHER_IRQ = TIMER_IRQ + 1;
`else
localparam SOME_OTHER_IRQ = TIMER_IRQ;
`endif
```